# Android Horizontally scrolling GridView

Tags: android

Has anyone been able to create of find an open source way to implement a horizontally scrolling Grid view? For phones a vertical scroll makes sense as apps are usually used in portrait mode, but on tablets when in landscape a left to right scroll seems much more usable then a top to bottom scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with a page swipe motion to swipe left and right one page at a time as demoed by Google in the Google IO 2011 app